# How to Call Block in Phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks

We saved some values in backend, we are displaying those values in [frontend](http://sbdevelopers.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases) using code written in `phtml` file.

Now we shifted code to block file, but now those `dropdown`  options are displaying in different positions as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases)

1) Is i am displaying code in wrong place ?

2) Is i need to call those block in phtml ?

```
class Company_Brand_Block_Frontend_Detail extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    protected $_faq;
    protected $_images;


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
          $brand = $this->getBrand();

        if ($brand !== false && $head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
            $head->setTitle($this->htmlEscape($brand->getBmodel()) . ' - ' . $head->getTitle());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to gather the current Brand item
     *
     * @return Company_Brand_Model_Brand The current brand item
     */
    public function getBrand() {
        if (!$this->_brand) {
            $id = intval($this->getRequest()->getParam('brand'));
            try {
                $this->_faq = Mage :: getModel('brand/brand')->load($id); 

                if ($this->_faq->getIsActive() != 1){
                    Mage::throwException('Brand Item is not active');
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_brand = false;
            }
        }

        return $this->_brand;
    }
}


$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = 'SELECT category_id, category_name FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('Company_advance_brand_category');

$categories = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$brandsArr = array();

$brandSelect = '<select id="brand_select">';
$brandSelect .= '<option value="">My Brand</option>';
foreach ($categories as $category){
$cat_id = $category["category_id"];

$brandSelect .= "<option value='".$category["category_id"]."'>".$category["category_name"]."</option>";

$query = 'SELECT `Company_advance_brand`.brand_id, `Company_advance_brand`.bmodel FROM `Company_advance_brand` ';
$query .= ' inner join `Company_advance_brand_category_item` on
(`Company_advance_brand`.brand_id = `Company_advance_brand_category_item`.brand_id )';
$query .= ' where `Company_advance_brand_category_item`.category_id = '.$cat_id;

$brands = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$bArr = array();

foreach ($brands as $brand){
$bArr[$brand["brand_id"]] = $brand["bmodel"];
}
$brandsArr[$cat_id] = $bArr;
}
$brandSelect .= '</select>';

echo $brandSelect;
echo '<select id="model_select"><option value="">My Model</option></select>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new method in block  and call that in phtml file like `echo $this->getOptions();`

```
class Outthink_Brand_Block_Frontend_Detail extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {


    public function getOptions()
    {
       $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = 'SELECT category_id, category_name FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('outthink_advance_brand_category');

$categories = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$brandsArr = array();

$brandSelect = '<select id="brand_select">';
$brandSelect .= '<option value="">My Brand</option>';
foreach ($categories as $category){
$cat_id = $category["category_id"];

$brandSelect .= "<option value='".$category["category_id"]."'>".$category["category_name"]."</option>";

$query = 'SELECT `outthink_advance_brand`.brand_id, `outthink_advance_brand`.bmodel FROM `outthink_advance_brand` ';
$query .= ' inner join `outthink_advance_brand_category_item` on
(`outthink_advance_brand`.brand_id = `outthink_advance_brand_category_item`.brand_id )';
$query .= ' where `outthink_advance_brand_category_item`.category_id = '.$cat_id;

$brands = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$bArr = array();

foreach ($brands as $brand){
$bArr[$brand["brand_id"]] = $brand["bmodel"];
}
$brandsArr[$cat_id] = $bArr;
}
$brandSelect .= '</select>';

return $brandSelect.'<select id="model_select"><option value="">My Model</option></select>';

    }
}
```